# I don't think I'm using an assumption in this proof. Anything wrong?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, proof-verification

Define the exponent $\exp(G)$ of a finite group $G$ to be the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $g^k = e$ for all $g \in G$.  The question asks

> If $G$ is a finite abelian group, prove that $G$ is cyclic if and only if $|G| = \exp(G)$.

I first assumed $|G| = \exp(G)$.  By definition, $\exp(G)$ is the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $g^k = e$ for every $g \in G$. Thus, there must exist an element of order $\exp(G) = |G|$, which shows that $G$ is cyclic.

Conversely, suppose $G$ is cyclic.  Then there is an element $g$ whose order is $|G|$. I had shown in a previous exercise that $\exp(G) \leq G$. Since there is an element of order $|G|$, this implies $\exp(G) = |G|$.

Is this OK?  I didn't use the assumption that $G$ is abelian anywhere, so I question if this proof holds.

Comment: I am not familiar with the order in which algebra is usually taught, having learned it myself 4 years ago.  But do you already know the prime factorization theorem for finite abelian groups?  If so, that may provide the easiest proof of all.

Comment: I know the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups, yes.  However, in the class I am currently taking we haven't been exposed to it.

Answer (score 2):

When $\exp(G)=|G|$, you did not explain why there must exist an element of order $|G|$ (and, in fact, this is not true). But the following *is* true: for $|G| = \prod_i p_i^{a_i}$, there exist elements $g_i$ of order $p_i^{a_i}$.

When $G$ is abelian, you can use this observation to finish the proof.

Answer (score 0):

To give you a clue, the first part - that the exponent of the group is equal to the order of the group implies the group is cyclic needs more work, and requires the abelian assumption. To see this note that there is a non-abelian group of order $21$ which has elements of order $3$ and order $7$ so the exponent is $21$ but it is not cyclic.

But if it were abelian ... perhaps you could see a way of making an element of order $21$, which would give the idea of the proof.

Comment: I could have course have used the more familiar example of the non-abelian group of order $6$ which has elements of order $2$ and $3$ hence exponent $6$. I try to avoid elements of order $2$ for examples in cases like this, because they sometimes have special properties which don't generalise.

Comment: Do I use the fact that the order is multiplicative in an abelian group?

Comment: @tylerc0816 It depends what you mean by multiplicative - the order of the product of two elements in an abelian group is the least common multiple of their orders, so is multiplicative if they are coprime.

Comment: On that note I have one more comment.  I had shown in a previous exercise that $exp(G) = \text{lcm} \{ o(g) : g \in G \}$.  Thus, can I just consider the element that is the product of each element in $G$ and note that it has order $exp(G) = |G|$?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @tylerc0816 The product of each element of $G$ will almost never work; in an abelian group, it always has order $1$ or $2$ (in the square, every element pairs with its inverse).

Comment: The order of the product of two elements will actually only be the lcm of their orders if you pick them in a lucky way (consider for example an element and its inverse). Given any two element orders in an abelian group, however, there will be some element with that lcm as its order.

Comment: @user33433 and it will only have order $2$ if the group has a Unique element of order $2$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks for that correction - should be "at most"